# Joining strings using logic conditions(for sql queries)

Tags: python, sql, string, python-3.x

I want to create an SQL query by concatenating strings but with conditions.

```
qs_str= 'Select *, from items ...'
```

The conditions:

```
if active:
            qs_str = ' '.join([qs_str, f'WHERE active=true'])
if is_parent:
          qs_str = ' '.join([qs_str, f'WHERE parent=true'])
if limit:
            qs_str = ' '.join([qs_str, f'WHERE LIMIT={limit}'])
.....
```

There is not really a fixed limit on how many conditions will be.

The issue is the `WHERE` clause, should be added only once(or not if there is no condition) and how to add `AND`, to know if a condition is already in place.

Because there is no theoretically limit for the number of conditions I can't
using combinatorics `ifs` like(if `is_active and is_parent`) is not a solution.

Comment: Dont Create Sql Statements Using String Concat - _**ever**_. use parametrized queries. Google Sql Injection, view [Exploits of a mum](https://xkcd.com/327/) + understand its explanation [for Exploits of a mum](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables)

Comment: Even if you had full control over your strings - using parametrized queries will make them faster - the SQL-Query-Optimizer can cache execution plans - if you provide a query with params it can reuse the execution plan for that query given other params. If you provide a strings w/o params multiple times, always adding other parameters into your string - it most probably won't reuse anything.

Comment: in this case the fields are boolean and number, besides having control, so I don't know how an sql injection can occur; but if you can provide  some help to using parametrized query for what I need I will use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the conditions in a list, and then only append the "where" clause if the list is non-empty.

Use `' and '.join(conditions)` to easily handle adding "and" exactly as needed.

```
def create_item_query(active=True, is_parent=True, limit=10):
    qs_str= 'select * from items'

    conditions = []

    if active:
        conditions.append('active=true')
    if is_parent:
        conditions.append('parent=true')
    if limit:
        conditions.append('LIMIT={limit:d}'.format(limit=limit))


    if conditions:
        qs_str += 'where ' + ' and '.join(conditions)

    return qs_str

print(create_item_query(True, True, 10))
print(create_item_query(True, False, None))
print(create_item_query(False, False, None))
```

Edit: I should point out that, as Patrick Artner mentioned in his comment, that it's not actually a good practice to build SQL queries as a string, due to the danger of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The precise way on how to create your queries would then depend on the exact SQL library that you're using (a popular tool is [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)).

Comment: the backend is Django, but I'm forced to use a raw query, because is more complex besides the conditions